# How can we get the list of all activitites on case?

Tags: apex, activities, case-object

I have to get the open activities, closed activities on case objects. I am having no idea how to get started with it. Can someone guide me on that.

I know that we have Activities History and Open Activities are there on case Object list but I am not able to access them.

Comment: are you trying to run a report to get the list of open/close activities ? or do you need this in code somehere ?

Comment: I have to run a report on the basis of open and closed activities classifying them on the basis of Email and phone call, with both incoming and outgoing activities

Comment: In a comment below, you ask how to do it programmatically, do you just want a SOQL query that will give you this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to get this..

- Go to Reports Tab -> Click on New Report
- Select **Activities with Cases** report
- In the report builder screen, use the filters section to Select All
  Activities , both open and closed
- Change your report format to Summary and group by Case number if you
  want
- add the required columns, Activity Type (phone/email), Status, etc.. from the left panel into the report columns

Comment: Can we do it programmatically

Comment: Use the following : SELECT Id,Subject from OpenActivities Where WhatId= "required_id"

Answer (score 0):

Create the report and add a filter for case id, but leave it blank. Then add a button to your case page layout that calls the report and passes in the case id.